# Does it exist: smart pointer, owned by one object allowing access

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm wondering if anyone's run across anything that exists which would fill this need.

Object A contains an object B.  It wants to provide access to that B to clients through a pointer (maybe there's the option it could be 0, or maybe the clients need to be copiable and yet hold references...whatever).  Clients, lets call them object C, would normally, if we're perfect developers, be written carefully so as to not violate the lifetime semantics of any pointer to B they might have...but we're not perfect, in fact we're pretty dumb half the time.

So what we want is for object C to have a pointer to object B that is not "shared" ownership but that is smart enough to recognize a situation in which the pointer is no longer valid, such as when object A is destroyed or it destroys object B.  Accessing this pointer when it's no longer valid would cause an assertion/exception/whatever.

In other words, I wish to share access to data in a safe, clear way but retain the original ownership semantics.  Currently, because I've not been able to find any shared pointer in which one of the objects owns it, I've been using shared_ptr in place of having such a thing.  But I want clear owneship and shared/weak pointer doesn't really provide that.

Would be nice further if this smart pointer could be attached to member variables and not just hold pointers to dynamically allocated memory regions.

If it doesn't exist I'm going to make it, so I first want to know if someone's already released something out there that does it.

And, BTW, I do realize that things like references and pointers do provide this sort of thing...I'm looking for something smarter.

Comment: Well, nobody's stepped up and pointed to one so at this point I'm assuming it's not out there.  Might check the Loki library just to see.  Answers so far are OK, and probably helpful for someone that doesn't know how to use weak_ptr, but I'm actually looking for something specifically designed for this purpose so I can't really accept either.

Answer (score 1):

[`boost::weak_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) is what you are looking for. Maybe with some minor tweaks though, like prohibiting creation of `shared_ptr` from it. Also, this can hold anything, including pointer to memory that is not dynamically allocated.

Comment: A `boost::weak_ptr` with disallowed creation of `shared_ptr` is pretty much useless - there is no other way to get the held object pointer than converting it to a `shared_ptr` (there are good reasons for it).

Comment: Disallowing creation of a shared_ptr from a weak_ptr seems to me like it would be of very limited use, and you'd just be begging to have a `bad_weak_ptr` exception thrown at you...

Comment: weak_ptr is part of the shared_ptr system.  I'm trying not to break the semantics of the system I'm using.

Comment: @Noah: Are you saying that you've considered `weak_ptr`, but are unsatisfied with it?  (Sorry if I've misunderstood). It seems prefect for what you need.  When Object B needs to call into Object B, it `lock()s` the weak_ptr to guarantee the object isn't nulled out during that single call, but as soon as its destructed you're only left with the weak_ptr again.

Comment: Anyone that you've given a weak_ptr can build and keep a shared_ptr.  No way to stop it.

Comment: Oh, and...  Disallowing, as policy, the creation of a shared_ptr from a weak_ptr, would be a bad plan I think.  The weak_ptr patr of the shared_ptr system is meant for a particular purpose, breaking cycles.  Members outside the cycle should be able to keep shared_ptrs of the item(s) that need to use this feature.  A policy that disallowed this would not be well advised IMNSHO.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics you want is similar to Qt's [`QPointer`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpointer.html). This is a pointer that can hold `QObject`s and nulls itself when the corresponding `QObject` is deleteed (ordinarily, eg. by `operator delete`).

However, similar approach has inherent problems - such that the client cannot be sure he isn't using a dangling pointer. eg.

```
QPointer<T> smart_ptr = original_obj;
T* tmp = smart_ptr; // this might be a function argument etc.

... // later
delete original_obj;

... // even later
tmp->do_something(); // CRASH
```

This can be avoided using some "hard" references that don't allow object deletion, which is exactly what `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` do.

BTW, AFAIK, `shared_ptr` can point to member variables, except it can't manage them. That is, you must provide a custom deleter that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yeah, I've used the shared_ptr(ptr, null_op) trick.  Looking for something that isn't a violation of the semantics of the system.  The null_op trick actually totally breaks down the whole shared_ptr thing.  You may as well not even have any sort of smart pointer at all.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: I don't think it breaks down the whole thing - you just get a `shared_ptr`, which may be useful if some library needs it. But yes, this is not intended usage of `shared_ptr`. You have to choose - either you take care of the deletion (this is always true for member variables) - and the clients must consider this and eg. _not violate the lifetime semantics_. Or it's the references that drive an object's lifetime - and in that case, it cannot be a member variable, since you can't guarantee how long will a reference to it last. Or use a garbage-collector. There's no other way.

Comment: It does.  You're not getting a real shared_ptr.  Sure, you get all the extra stuff that comes with a shared_ptr, and it'll work in a pinch, but in reality the shared_ptr is completely superfluous and none of what shared_ptr is made to do has any effect.  This is why I'm looking for something that does it right.  Thanks anyway though.  Keep checking my blog for when I write it :p